# The answer to this riddle has a hole in the middle

Tags: riddle, word

Here's an easy riddle I got from a book:

> *The answer to this riddle has a hole in the middle,
>   
> And some have been known to fall in it.
>   
> In tennis, it's nothing, but it can be recieved,
>   
> And sometimes a person may win it.
>   
> Though it's not seen or heard it may yet be percieved,
>   
> Like princes or bees it's in clover.
>   
> The answer to this riddle has a hole in the middle,
>   
> And without it, one cannot start over.*

Comment: Oh, I recognize this! It's from the Mysterious Benedict Society series - I used to love those books!

Comment: @Deusovi I know they were awesome!

Comment: Book 2, right? :) (I especially liked this riddle as a tennis player)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Heres my guess:

Answer:

> Love

Reasoning:
The answer to this riddle has a hole in the middle,

> the letter o is a hole and in the middle (kind of) of the word love

And some have been known to fall in it.

> You can fall in love

In tennis, it's nothing, but it can be recieved,

> Love in tennis is 0

And sometimes a person may win it.

> You can woo someone and "win their love" from @Matt

Though it's not seen or heard it may yet be percieved,

> Not a physical object but can be felt

Like princes or bees it's in clover.

> Princes love to be in clover (rich) and bees love to be in clovers (plant)

The answer to this riddle has a hole in the middle,

> Same as first line

And without it, one cannot start over.

> Over starts with o, which is in the middle of love

Comment: Ah, beat me to it!

Comment: 'In clover' refers to different things for 'princes' and 'bees'.

Comment: Think about the word 'over'...

Comment: I'd L`o`ve to know about the word `O`ver, too.

Comment: "It's in clover" looks to me to clearly be referring to c__**love**__r.

Comment: @Hellion You may wish to check the edit history on this one.