# RIDDÅL - another unfinished flat-pack puzzle

Tags: riddle, cipher, rebus, no-computers, mechanical-puzzles

*This is an entry to the [19th Fortnightly topic challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5614/fortnightly-topic-challenge-19-unconventional-tag-fusion?cb=1)*

Yesterday I got a package in the mail. Attached to its top was a letter:

> Dear Alconja,

That's strange, I thought... Must have gone to the wrong user.

> As a result of your excellent choice in purchasing a **REJBÄS** puzzle, you have been invited to user test the new **RIDDÅL** puzzle. It is intended to be harder and more complicated than the **REJBÄS** and to have more ambiguous instructions.
>
> Please send your feedback in reply mail once you have finished the puzzle (with your solution in case multiple can be found).
>
> Thank you!
>
> N.B. Also, once you open the package the materials will self-destruct in exactly one minute.

So I got my scanner ready and opened the package. There was an instruction booklet, a trapezoidal grid tiled by triangles with letters and a black and white hexagon, also tiled by triangles and with an arrow and the code PLZ-SE-95R.

I couldn't make heads or tails of it, so I wondered whether anyone could solve it for me. Maybe [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja) themself could solve it...

Anyway, here are the scans. They got progressively worse as the minute ticked down:

[The instruction booklet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wqh5eu8m4t9eza/RIDD%C3%85L%20instructions.pdf?dl=0)

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

[image: Page 3]

[image: Page 4]

[image: Page 5]

The trapezium

[image: Trapezium]

The hexagon

[image: PLZ-SE-95R]

Notes:

- They weren't scanned to the correct size.
- The trapezium was printed on both sides, but was printed as if the ink had gone straight through the cardboard (so I didn't scan it).
- The hexagon was printed only on one side
- The link to the instruction booklet has a PDF on Dropbox
- The number in step 13 is, to the best of my knowledge, 67857383296491225625081879653534944430162017097746438655845348065271398002936105813847401195885432.87149223286951755978260113706096896662684272363707639031761219104950570374243315214582045841

Credits:

> [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja) for the inspiration ([here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43276/rejb%C3%84s-an-unfinished-flat-pack-puzzle)) and some of the images.
>
> [This book series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Benedict_Society) (<s>will be</s> *was* revealed when the puzzle <s>is</s> *was* solved) for the riddle...

Hints:

1. (Step 1)

   > The first step isn't totally necessary from a puzzle-solving point of view, but is needed for [mechanical-puzzles](/questions/tagged/mechanical-puzzles) where one of the stipulations is [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers)
2. (Step 1)

   > The crosses in the first step symbolise something other than 'don't cut'
3. (Step 1)

   > Step 1 is purposely ambiguous - it is not meant to be taken literally
4. (Step 2)

   > The shapes in step 2 are meant to be generic
5. (Step 2)

   > The `r`'s in step 2 could plausibly represent two things - they represent both...
6. (Step 2)

   > This step is easier to do mechanically than on a computer
7. (Step 3)

   > The black triangle isn't just any triangle
8. (Step 3)

   > You need to make an observation about a seemingly innocuous aspect of the puzzle to do this step
9. (Step 3)

   > This step requires the previous step unlike step 2
10. (Step 4)

    > Is there something asymmetric about the picture?
11. (Step 4)

    > This should only be done once
12. (Step 4)

    > It should be applied to an object, not the absence of one

Comment: By the way, since there are many steps involved in solving the puzzle, a progress post might be helpful.

Comment: Do we not have any pieces like the last one?

Comment: Just the one trapezoidal piece @BeastlyGerbil.

Comment: Step 4 is likely to be "leapfrog", since it's a frog with the leap day date on its back.

Comment: Could 5 be SU40 ? The image seems to be hardly inspired by SuperUser... Just busdrive thoughts though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are instructions for an ikea furniture

Comment: @PersyJack The theme of this puzzle is confusing IKEA flatpack instructions. You might want to look at Alconja's puzzle as well (linked in the credits).

Comment: In case anyone wants the Hexagon with 24, or 96 pieces check out this Android app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.weebmeister.picflip it also has a 20/80 3D variant on an icosaeder. You might need to tweak and load the scans from above and use them on the foto puzzle

Comment: so on `R` on the front of the trapezium appears as `Я` on the back ?

Comment: @Jasen yes. Also, if something was in the top-left corner on the front it would be on the top-right corner on the back, and vice-versa.

Comment: ...you keep adding hints further and further into the puzzle, but has anyone actually worked out how to deal with step 2 yet? Not much point providing hints to step 4 if we can't even get there...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Step 1

> This is a small section of the trapezoid, so we need to cut the trapezoid apart (maybe into each triangle, maybe into different pieces)
>
>   And don't cut apart the hexagon with PLZ-SE-95R (?)
>
>   [image]

### Step 2

> Transform the trapezium into the hexagon by following the path of an S (snaking) for the input and spiraling inwards for the output. You'll notice that doing this on the trapezium would seem a bit off as you end up with non-alternating directions.
>
>   This can be fixed by following the accompanying text of r0r180r0r180r0. This corresponds to the five rows on the trapezium. Rotate the second and fourth rows.
>
>  Here are the diagrams for the transformation:
>  [image]
>  [image]

### Step 3

> After the transformation we notice that one spot is missing. The black triangle on the instructions refers to that, so draw a line straight down from it.
>   [image]

### Step 4

> Leapfrog (from **Dan Russell**)
>
>  Hop over to the right, twice.
>  [image]

### Step 5

> We can fill in the blanks with WD, forming WD-40, a well-known lubricant.
>
>   Draw a line from the single **W** to the single **D**.
>
>   [image]

### Step 6

> Swap the two sets of two triangles along the pivot.
>   [image]

### Step 7

> As in Step 4, we will be flipping triangles into the hole. The side and order is specified by the - \ / sequence.
>
>   [image]

### Step 8

> Draw lines! On the entire 96 triangle hexagon formed from step 2 and whatever other transformations may have occurred.
>  [image]

### Step 9

> Flip horizontally the triangles inside of the areas specified.
>  [image]

### Step 10

> There is only one section of the puzzle where you see that pattern of marks we've made (on the right side). Apply the transformations to that set of triangles.
>  [image]

### Step 11

> Draw a line.
>  [image]

### Step 12

> Completely fill triangles that look like that (with the line through it)
>  [image]

### Step 13

> Can be broken up into 96 pairs (**.** being a pair, maybe confirming that we have an empty space). A reordering of the triangles.
>
> ```
> Sequence: 67 85 73 83 29 64 91 22 56 25 08 18 79 65 35 34 94 44 30 16 20 17 09 77 46 43 86 55 84 53 48 06 52 71 39 80 02 93 61 05 81 38 47 40 11 95 88 54 32 .  87 14 92 23 28 69 51 75 59 78 26 01 13 70 60 96 89 66 62 68 42 72 36 37 07 63 90 31 76 12 19 10 49 50 57 03 74 24 33 15 21 45 82 04 58 41
> Index:    01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96
> ```
>
> [image]
>  [image]

### Finally

> I must've done something funky, but taking the letters from left to right, top to bottom, we have
>
> ```
> GURNFAJREGBGUVFEVQQYRUNFNUBYRAGURZVQQYVNAQFBZRUNIROAXABJAGBSNYYVVGVAGRAAVFVGFABGUVATOHGGPNAORERPRVIRQNAQFBZRGVZRFNCREFBAZNLJVAVGGUBHTAUBGFRRABEURNEQVGZLLRGORCREPRVIRQYVXRCEVAPRFBEORRFVGFVAPYBIREGURNAFJREGBGUVFEVQQYRUNFNUBYRVAGURZVQQYRNAQJVGUBHCNVGBAOPNAABGCGNEGSIREKK
> ```
>
> The resulting image clues us to ROT13. We get:
>
> ```
> THEASNWERTOTHISRIDDLEHASAHOLENTHEMIDDLIANDSOMEHAVEBNKNOWNTOFALLIITINTENNISITSNOTHINGBUTTCANBERECEIVEDANDSOMETIMESAPERSONMAYWINITTHOUGNHOTSEENORHEARDITMYYETBEPERCEIVEDLIKEPRINCESORBEESITSINCLOVERTHEANSWERTOTHISRIDDLEHASAHOLEINTHEMIDDLEANDWITHOUPAITONBCANNOTPTARTFVERXX
> ```
>
> THE ASNWER TO THIS RIDDLE HAS A HOLE N THE MIDDLI AND SOME HAVE BN KNOWN TO FALL IITIN TENNIS ITS NOTHING BUTT CAN BE RECEIVED AND SOMETIMES A PERSON MAY WIN IT THOUGN HOT SEEN OR HEARD IT MY YET BE PERCEIVED LIKE PRINCES OR BEES ITS IN CLOVER THE ANSWER TO THIS RIDDLE HAS A HOLE IN THE MIDDLE AND WITHOUP A IT ON B CANNOT PTART FVERXX
>
>  It seems that the answer to this riddle is: **LOVE**
>
>  The hole is the letter 'O'.
>  In tennis, love is a term for the score 0, which is nothing.
>  ...something about winning it and being perceived like princes and bees...
>  C**LOVE**R
>  And I can't make sense of the end.

Comment: Indeed it is easier to do it manually, it was a pain for me to digitalise it all. If you post progress at each step (take a picture if you're doing it by hand), I'll tell you whether you're on the right track or not. What's stopping you from continuing?

Comment: @boboquack I've been busy, I stop by whenever I can, but don't have too much time.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I've just realised that in my digitisation, the triangles were all rotated individually, instead of the whole row being rotated D: Damn triangles indeed. Anyway, I don't have time \*right\* now, but I could change it for you if you want?

Comment: @boboquack Isn't that the same thing? Or if you meant that the second and fourth rows were meant to be placed in reverse of what I did then... *grooaaann*. Feel free to change what you'd like haha

Comment: No, your row is currently ARQT, VNFE, JKLZ, ..., BQNI, HHIH, GIZF; but the row should be GIZF, HHIH, BQNI, ..., JKLZ, VNFE, ARQT, just with the triangles r180. Also, the leapfrog should be not just 1 across, but 2 across (not $\triangle=\triangledown\implies\triangle$ but $\triangle=\triangledown=\triangle=\triangledown\implies\triangle$). For all the effort you've put in, I'm going to put a big bounty on this answer, sorry for all the errors.

Comment: I'll fix and redo the steps next week :P

Comment: It's been more than a week...

Comment: I would LOVE to see this finished

Comment: One week later....

Comment: Wow, great work! Unfortunately I have lost my notes for this puzzle in one spring cleaning or another, so I can't say which step didn't work out completely well, but I can confirm the final answer is correct! Looks like whatever bounty I said I was going to award went astray, here's another one for good measure.

Comment: Also, [relevant](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32884/the-answer-to-this-riddle-has-a-hole-in-the-middle)

Answer (score 7):

## Partial Answer

Observations about the trapezium:

> When rotated and mirrored (note says ink went through) to align the letters there are 47 triangles that point upwards and 46 that point downwards with 2 triangles that could work either way. There are 95 faces overall, which is 5×19.
>
>  There are 1 M, 1 D and 1 W in the trapezium, all the other letters have several occurrences.

Transcription of the trapezium:

> Triangles that point upwards, letters are top, mid, left, right:
>  UNCV, VRRO, TJSW, QPCK, SIKX, IFGG, EENF, AAVA or AAAV, AGBG, RFBI, SXAZ, ICOS, BQNI, LTLS, COLK, SHJT, FRUV, VRAV, BFBG, YFHG, NRBE, JKLZ, VNFE, GRUV, JGQY, RRRU, HTST, BQJV, UECE, JSCO, CCTO, FVZR, TXZK, LHTS, RVLJ, AGGP, FGGB, UAAX or UAXA, NGEV, RRQF, FEAU, YFQQ, ANEK, ORAZ, VVPR, ZBFR, NCBH
>
>  Triangles that point downwards, letters are left, right, mid, bottom:
>  AGRH, FABQ, VYUB, COCI, HIQP, PRZV, VAAA, UNZB, YRQG, RACX, ZIMH, GZIF, GBAT, QPQK, RNPV, AGNR, VGUG, BERR, NUVQ, AQRT, NUQU, DCOV, JXST, YRYR, ORVR, BJRU, PNGR, RQNU, OZHL, ZCLK, UREF, HOOI or OHOI, HTIJ, LLQO, SNVO, EQRA, RGYR, BAGG, YVVV or VYVV, ABEK, RZAG, BIJY, XZZK, AAPV, VGFN, REGN
>
>  Triangles that could point either way:
>  If downwards: HHIH, IKKK
>  If upwards: HIHH, KKKI
>
>  Letter occurances:
>
> ```
> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
> BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCC
> D
> EEEEEEEEEEEEEE
> FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
> GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
> HHHHHHHHHHHHHH
> IIIIIIIIIIIIII
> JJJJJJJJJJJ
> KKKKKKKKKKKKK
> LLLLLLLLLL
> M
> NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
> OOOOOOOOOOOOOO
> PPPPPPPPP
> QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
> RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
> SSSSSSSSSSS
> TTTTTTTTTTTT
> UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
> VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
> W
> XXXXXXX
> YYYYYYYYYY
> ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
> ```

Another observation:

> Based on the letter frequency compared to English a shift by 13 characters makes sense.

Comment: Good start! Now start doing each step in turn.

Comment: However, you haven't got the correct number of triangles on the trapezium.

Comment: Hint: The top-right triangle is oriented the right way up: it is ZIMH

Comment: @boboquack Welp, I assumed default fonts where the M and W are different and this looked like a W. Also this post was mainly meant as a help for others. But when I have more time, I will definitely try to solve it.

Comment: Unfortunately Futura (IKEA's font) doesn't distinguish very well.

Comment: I have awarded the bounty to your answer, though I still think this question needs more attention.

Comment: What's stopping you from continuing? If you post progress at each step, I'll tell you if you're on the right track or not.